# I moved the build output box to its own window. How do I move it back?

Tags: visual-studio, output-window

I had the Output box set to show underneath my code. I accidentally pulled it out from there and it became its own window. I can close the window and go to View, click Output, and it comes back, still as a window! How can I set it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All windows within Visual Studio are dockable. You need to find the sweet spot for where the overlay menu shows up allowing you to dock your window in a certain position.

Drag the window towards the bottom until this overlay menu shows up, then choose the bottom position and it will dock below again.

Answer (score 2):

Grab the output window and drag it back over visual studio, you should get a bunch of visual helpers that pop up to help you dock it back in place where you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Drag the window until some of the anchors appear and then drop it there on the bottom anchor in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the title bar of the output window and start to drag it. It will "pop out" and you can move it to the bottom of your screen (or wherever you like). There are guides to show you where you can place the window.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to have the various output windows available as tabs at the bottom of Visual Studio

If you have none, then dock a window, it will go to the bottom

For the next, drag the window over the existing docked window so that the draggable area is over the draggable area of the docked window. Let the window drop and you should have the tabbed windows at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022 I had to grab Output window to middle than from middle I could move it to bottom. It was not working directly in first step to drag to bottom, the anchor didn't appear.